# Writing PGM file in C doesn't work

Tags: c, pgm

I am trying to write a PGM file in a C program, but once it is written, if I try to open it to view the image I am told the image file format can't be determined.

However, if I create a new file in geany, copy the data over, and then save THAT as a new PGM, it works.

Any idea why this could be?

```
FILE * grey = fopen("greyscale.pgm", "w");

fprintf(grey, "P2 \r\n%d %d \r\n255 \r\n", width, height);

for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        fprintf(grey, "%d ", ((imageArray[i][j].red + imageArray[i][j].green + imageArray[i][j].blue)/3));
    }
    fprintf(grey, "\r\n");
}
```

I am converting a colour image to greyscale.

Comment: It could be related with the header of your PGM file. Could you add the piece of code that create the PGM file?

Comment: 1/3 is not a good coefficient when you convert RGB to gray. Try `0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B` which is a widespread formula.

Comment: Thanks, Benoit. It looks much better with that formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not use `\r\n` as a line delimiter, but only `\n`. Also, check that no line has above 70 characters in length. Since each pixel needs at most 4 characters (3 plus space) insert `\n` after every 17 pixels.
You can separate real lines with comments (for example:

```
pixel11 pixel12 pixel13
pixel14 pixel15
# switch to next row
pixel21 pixel22 pixel23
pixel24 pixel25
# etc.
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it working. I think it was a problem with the amount of whitespace in the header or after it or something.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I see that you insert a `new line` every `height` elements. According with the PGM file format, after the header, follows

- A **raster of Height rows**, in order from top to bottom. Each row consists of Width gray values, in order from left to right.

But your are writing  a row of height element. So, your are probably accessing data in a wrong way. In fact, try to debug (with a pencil) an image of 3 columns (width) and 4 rows (height).

Said that, change your loop to write data in row-major order:

```
// write data to file
int row, col;
for (row = 0; row < height; ++row)
{
    for (col = 0; col < width; ++col)
    {
        fprintf(grey, "%d ", (imageArray[row][col].red + imageArray[row][col].green + imageArray[row][col].blue)/3));
    }
    fprintf(grey, "\n\r");
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I am doing... I just put my code in the OP.

Comment: I did not notice you were writing an ascii file

Comment: I was originally writing a binary file... that didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. I know I have height and width the wrong way around, but that's just me naming it wrong when I initially read the data in.